# How to handle related entities in an event sourced aggregate

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm adventuring myself in the world of ES and CQRS and I've been reading a lot about it. Unfortunately, most materials don't go beyond the basics and when you start trying to apply it to real-world examples you start stumbling into stuff not covered in the examples.

My question is regarding related entities. Imagine we have a `Product` aggregate that is event sourced and a `Category` entity. `Product` has one `Category` property. But please don't stick the entity/concept names, they're just examples.

`Category` might not be an aggregate by itself, but since you have many products in one category, the list of categories is saved separately from the `Product` aggregate.

When I save an instance of a `Product` I store the `id` of the `Category` entity.

My question is when I need to rebuild a `Product` from the events.

The aggregate will be reconstructed and will have the category id only instead of a category reference.

Now if I need to perform some business logic based on some state of the category, I cannot.

I could have another 'complete' `Product` model, then I would construct it based on the original persisted `Product`, and for the related entities I would have to go through the whole list of categories, find the one needed and set the property in the 'complete' `Product`. I don't know, but something doesn't seem right with this approach.

What's the usual approach in such a situation?

Comment: does Product have product.CategoryId or product.Category? if the later, then its all saved together, if the former you dont need to load the category

Comment: It does have `CategoryId`, but saying in this situation you don't need to load the category is not correct. As I said, we might have a business logic that would be dependent on the category of the product. Imagine some categories add an x% amount to the product price. Then we would have something like `Product.CalculateFinalPrice()` which would need information form the category.

Comment: you would have new pricecalcservice(catagoryRepository); price = pricecalcservice.calcPrice(product). because the product AR doesnt have Category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I think your question is complex because you have a number of competing ideas here. Event Sourcing, Aggregate Roots, OOP.

**Event Sourcing**

Event sourcing works great with methods on objects that are pure functions. If I have `Room.CloseDoor()` I can save that as an Event and replay it to rebuild the object state. If I change the logic I can still replay the event and get the new valid object state.

It works passably with methods on objects that take simple parameters. `Room.AdjustLight(100)` can be saved as an Event + Data and be replayed as before.

If you have external data though it doesn't work at all `Room.LetWhateverAnimalIsOutsideIn(outsideAnimalsRepository)` doesnt work at all, because the external data can change between rebuilds and you get random results.

This is equivalent to your `product.GetPrice(categoryRepo)` call. Even though you know what category the product has, you can't know what data will be returned from the category repository.

The common way to deal with this is to replace the 'logic' events with a set value event for the result of the logic. So here `CalcPrice` would become `SetPrice, £X` where the value of the price is the data associated with the event.

Unfortunately this does tend to undermine the whole Event Sourcing ideal though. As all your events become `SetX, Y` and you really have no benefit over just saving the state of the object.

Event Sourcing trys to combat this by differentiating between internal and external events. So you still have the `product.CalcPrice` method, and keep all setters hidden, but only persist private setter events.

**Aggregate Roots and OOP**

Now if we talk about Aggregate Roots for a sec. This idea comes from Domain Driven Design and I think here you have another issue in that DDD is fundamentally opposed to OOP.

I'm prob going to get some downvotes for that, and I don't want to spend too long explaining why I'm right, but essentially DDD wants to have the same Data be treated differently in different contexts. So the WebSites `Product` isn't the same as the accounting departments `Product` This leads to the separation of the product Data, which is the same for all contexts and the methods you want to run on that data. Whereas OOP wants you to keep the data and methods together.

This leads to my advice which is : If you are using ARs you should not have any methods on your objects. Keep them as simple data structures and put all the logic in Domain Services. ie. PriceCalculator.Calc(Product)

This allows you to have a single Product object, solves your issue with out of AR links, (as services can have any other injected services and repos they require to get extra data) and works well with ES (although makes its utility questionable), because you only have property set events to deal with.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in the time and effort to answer this. My domains usually need some related entities that are just lists of values, like category in this example, source, etc. I added the `CalculatePrice()` method to the example because I can see it happening in some domains, but my actual concern is how to deal with related entities. This answer at least helps me to understand that this is not a trivial scenario and is probably the reason I don't see many examples like this.